# How can I Localize anomalies with heatmaps using autoencoder?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, autoencoder, anomaly-detection

I am working on anomaly detection model (for PCBs) using Autoencoder , I am working on google Colab using free GPU. so as a first step I was trying to build my autoencoder and visualise the reconstruction of my training data(pictures without defects size 1,3 MP). I built a model of three layers with 150 epochs batch size =2,  it gave me good results. I used SSIM loss function to calculate the difference between the test photos  ( pictures with aomalies) and the training data(pictures without anomalies). The problem here that I want to visualize these differences with the HeatMap as I read in some articles that it is possible to localize anomalies in a pixel level .. I suppose it is related to the loss function that we use to calculate the difference.

do you have any idea what functions could help me visualize/Localize anomalies ?

Comment: Are you using a reconstructing autoencoder?

Comment: Yes, I am using a reconstructing autoencoder, I tried it on my training data after training the autoencoder and it gave me the same input so I assumed it is working, but when trying it on my test data ( an anomalous image) it also gave me the same input (using autoenoder.predict) so when calculating the difference between the input image and the generated image ( in the case of anomalous image) the difference was very low unlike the REAL difference between the anomalous and non anomalous data.. so I don't know what am I missing ..

Comment: I inspired the way to work from this article but with  electronic boards real photos as a dataset:
https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/anomaly-detection-in-images-autoencoders-b780abf88f51

Comment: You should plot the distribution of scores between anomaly and normal instances. The range of score values is dependent model (data, architecture, loss, hyperparameters, etc.), and may need to be normalized to a standard range (0.0-1.0 etc).

Answer (score 0):

The task of outputting where in an image is known as Anomaly Localization. There are many academic papers on the topic for advanced methods.

When using a reconstructing autoencoder on images for anomaly detection, one can compute the difference between the input image and the reconstructed output image as an anomaly-level image.